# Why can't I connect to mongoDB atlas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am new in MongoDB, all my life I used MySQL.

I have created an account in atlas, set the IP to my IP and created a user and saved the password.

here is my code, why doesn't it work?

app.js

```html
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoPractice = require('./mongo');


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/products', mongoPractice.createProduct);

app.get('/products');

app.listen(3000);
```

and the mongo.js:

```html
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const url =
  "mongodb+srv://idan:<85IwoSzeQssHMzLN>@cluster0.tpejv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  const newProduct = {
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
  };
  const client = new MongoClient(url);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db();
    const result = db.collection("products").insertOne(newProduct);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json(error);
  }
  client.close();

  res.json(newProduct);
};

const getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {};

exports.createProduct = createProduct;
exports.getProducts = getProducts;
```

the POSTMAN output:

[image]

Comment: You should add MongoDb Address correctly. It should have user and password of db user added to database in MongoDB Atlas. remove <> from url.

Comment: Change your password too since I can guess your password now I think;)

Answer (score 1):

Your ip may have changed, (check if the current ip address has information `"(includes your current IP address)"`. For testing(!) you can add address 0.0.0.0/0 to the whitelist - it means every ip will be accepted - this solution is good for beginners

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly check you connection link from mongodb connect
2. Check username, password again
3. You can change password and try again

Answer (score 0):

In mongo.js

You need to remove "< >" around the password.

```js
const url = "mongodb+srv://idan:**85IwoSzeQssHMzLN**@cluster0.tpejv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error once and I might have solution.

**The most common one** is that your IP address set to access the database might not match with your current IP address in which case you need to set it to your current IP or set to `allow access from anywhere.`

**The issue which I had** : If you have recently started using an `ethernet cable` try going `back to wireless` to access the mongoDB database from your backend script.